# Connecting to durable consumer - Qpid Proton Python

Tags: python, activemq-classic, amqp, qpid

I'm trying to get a Qpid Proton Python client to subscribe to an ActiveMQ broker over AMQP v1.0 as a durable consumer.

I can create a durable subscription but don't quite understand how to pick up the same subscription the next time my script runs.

After each run, the ActiveMQ admin console shows that a durable subscription has been created, and it is named according to my script's input, but the next run just creates another rather than connects to the one previously created.

I think I might be missing the creation of a "ClientID" (as ActiveMQ calls it) but can't see (in the Qpid Proton documentation) how to set it.

Here's my code:-

```
def on_start(self, event):
    if self.subscription_name:
        logging.debug("Naming durable subscription " + self.subscription_name)
        durable = DurableSubscription()
    else:
        logging.debug("Subscription will not be durable")
        durable = None

    messaging_connection = event.container.connect(self.url)
    logging.info(messaging_connection.clientID)
    event.container.create_receiver(
        messaging_connection,
        self.resource,
        name=self.subscription_name,
        options=durable
    )
    logging.debug("Connected to " + self.url + "/" + self.resource)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this (with help from the Qpid users mailing list).

As suspected, I needed to name the client connection.  This is done by adding the following line of code before calling the `connect` method.

```
event.container.container_id = __file__
```

(NB I simply gave the connection the same name as the script)

Another gotcha was that the `event.receiver.close()` method, called once my script had processed all messages, destroys the durable subscription.  To leave it in place after the script has ended, use `event.receiver.detach()` instead.

Mailing list thread here -> http://qpid.2158936.n2.nabble.com/Connecting-to-durable-consumer-Qpid-Proton-Python-td7659185.html